# Calculating residue in exponential fraction

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to calculate the residue of $$\dfrac{e^{it}}{e^t+e^{-t}}$$ at $t=\pi i/2$.

To calculate the residue at $\pi i/2$, I write

$$\frac{e^{it}}{e^t+e^{-t}}=\frac{e^{it}e^t}{e^{2t}+1}=\frac{e^{it}e^t}{(e^t+i)(e^t-i)}$$so the residue is $$\frac{e^{i\pi i/2}e^{\pi i/2}}{(e^{\pi i/2}+i)}=\frac{e^{-\pi/2}i}{2i}=\dfrac{e^{-\pi/2}}{2}$$ Is this a correct way to calculate the residue? I just want to make sure I understand it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're off to a good start! From your work, you can see that $\pi i/2$ is a simple pole, so you can calculate the residue as
$$
\lim_{t \to \pi i/2} (t - \pi i/2) \left( \frac{e^{it}e^t}{(e^t+i)(e^t-i)} \right).
$$
From here it might help to notice that 
$$
\frac{t-\pi i/2}{e^t - i} = \frac{t-\pi i/2}{e^t - e^{\pi i/2}}
$$
and think derivatives.

In general, if you have a simple pole at $t_0$ of a map $f$, then the residue of $f$ at $t_0$ can be calculated by 
$$
\operatorname{Res}(f,t_0) = \lim_{t\to t_0} (t-t_0)f(t).
$$

Answer (score 2):

You can use the fact that, when $f(z)=p(z)/q(z)$ has a simple pole at $z=z_0$, the residue of $f$ at $z=z_0$ is $p(z_0)/q'(z_0)$.  In this case, $p(z)=e^{i t}$ and $q(z)=2 \cosh{t}$.  Therefore the residue is $e^{-\pi/2}/(2 i)$.